# What is triggering this Leaflet map click?

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with a custom control that consists of a simple form with an `<input>` and a `<button>`.

[image]

The problem I'm having is that **when you submit the form by hitting the Enter key, it also triggers a `click` event on the map**. Interestingly, the `originalEvent` property of the click event object is a `KeyboardEvent` with a key code of `13` (the Enter key). Somehow, one is leading to the other and I can't figure out why.

This is what my `Control` subclass looks like:

```
import { Control, DomEvent } from 'leaflet';

class ControlParent extends Control {
    constructor(el, options) {
      super(options);
      this.el = el;
    }
    onAdd() {
      const el = this.el;

      // keep clicks from hitting the map
      DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(el);

      return el;
    }
  }
```

Can anyone think of what's causing this and what steps I can take to keep it from propagating?

Comment: your import looks strange. Are you sure it's working ? import L from 'leaflet'; and then L.DomeEvent.....

Comment: @AlexParij yes, the import works fine.